# CloudFoundry Trace and the case of the Private Data

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I'm trying to write a client in NodeJS to exercise my applications on a Cloud Foundry server. I have already discovered many of the steps to actually login, but a few are elusive.

Using the `CF_TRACE=true cf auth` command I can see the HTTP Requests, but when it comes to that *one* header I need I get a `Authorization: [PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]`. Is there a trick I can pull to remove that? :pew:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look through the CF source code for where this is happening.
I don't believe it's possible to change this via a configuration flag.